# Creating a data series linear trend to fill between cells in the same column

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I am currently working with a modified collection of data with gaps in each recorded value. I would like to use Excel's fill utility under the Home tab (editing(group)->fill->series. with Rows,linear,trend) to generate values with a linear trend. I am working with a range from A2:A6569 so manually doing this is not practical. I have generated this data using an Excel function if statement, where if its not calling a value, its placing ("") in each cell. Everything that I've found and tried is not working.

Data Sample: (where x is a blank cell)

1. "title"
2. 0.004
3. x
4. x
5. x
6. 5.214
7. x
8. x
9. 7.01
10. x
11. x
12. x
13. 6.97

Pseudo code of what I have tried:

```vb
    Dim rStoA, rStoB, rStoC As Range
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A6569")
        for each value in range 
            if IsNumeric(value) And IsEmpty(rStoA) Then
                rStoA = value
            else if IsNumeric(value) and IsNumeric(rStoA) Then
                rStoB = value
                Set rStoC = .Range(rStoA, rStoB)
                rStoC.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, 
                  Date:=xlDay, Trend:=True
                rStoA = rStoB
            end if
        next
    End With
```

From recording a macro, I have found the function I need from Excel's fill utility:

```
"selected_range".DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, Trend:=True
```

I believe that my problem is my use of Range's but I am stuck.

Also, would it be better if I were to use Range.Find? If so, could someone steer me in the right direction with that?

I appreciate any advice.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you are trying to do right, you could do something like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fillSeries()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range
Dim fillRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long
Dim fillCol As String
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet")
lastRow = 13 'the row of the last cell you want to fill
firstRow = 2 'the row where your data begins
fillCol = "A" 'the column to be filled

For Each cell In Range(sht.Cells(firstRow, fillCol), sht.Cells(lastRow, fillCol))
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next cell
Set firstCell = sht.Range(fillCol & firstRow)
While firstCell.Row <> lastRow
    If firstCell.End(xlDown).Row > lastRow Then
        Set lastCell = sht.Range(fillCol & lastRow)
    Else
        Set lastCell = firstCell.End(xlDown)
    End If
    sht.Range(firstCell, lastCell).DataSeries Type:=xlLinear, Trend:=True
    Set firstCell = lastCell
Wend

End Sub
```

Basically, the code finds pairs of non blank cells, that are separated by blank cells and fills those blanks in between. The last cell of the previously used pair becomes the first of the next one and so on until the last cell is reached.

I am not sure if the last cell of the range is already filled or not so I built the code in a way so you can define manually which cell is the last one.

So, for the data sample you've provided, assuming that the filling should stop at row 13 (where 6,97 is), the result would be the following:

[image]

If you would like to continue the filling until say row 20, the result would be:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is happening on my end but I am not getting the same results as you. It appears that the range the .dataseries is using is just the initial l firstRow and lastRow. Reading into the Range.End property it suggests that it will find the last cell in the column that contains data. Which I believe confirms what I am experiencing.

Comment: @CritF I just realised that cells in between values are not completely blank. `.End` doesn't find the last cell. What it does is it skips **completely** blank cells and "jumps" from one non-blank cell to the next one. It basically imitates the `ctrl + down` behaviour. The code above assumes that the cells which you have denoted with an x, have no contents whatsoever. In your case however, since these cells are being completed by a formula with a "", they are not blank. I have updated the code to first clear the contents of these cells and then perform the filling.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!